# ASMX web methods are not invoking on azure webapp

Tags: web-services, azure

I have developed the web app and it is hosted on Azure. Web app having one typeahead and data for this typeahead is getting from Web service having web method 'AutocompleteSuggestions'.
When I go to ASMX file address like 'abc.azurewebsites.net/MyWebService.asmx' it will show the web method name and after clicking on that web method 'invoke' button appears. After clicking on 'Invoke' it will show '*The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable*.' It is working fine on the local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by changing the location of MyWebService.asmx file. I put MyWebService.asmx file in the folder of that perticular module not in the root folder. The path is changed from 'abc.azurewebsites.net/MyWebService.asmx' to 'abc.azurewebsites.net/Module1/MyWebService.asmx'.